# Open colon ⦂ using \Umathchar as an ordinary symbol

Tags: math-mode, xetex, symbols, luatex, unicode-math

By default, the open colon “⦂” is a relation symbol in unicode-math.  How do I typeset “⦂” *directly* in {`xe`|`lua`}`latex` using `\Umathchar` as an ordinary, i.e., unspaced symbol?

So far I've been writing `\mathord{⦂}`:

```
\newcommand{\unspacedOpenColon}{\mathord{⦂}}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\unspacedOpenColon}{{⦂}}
```

However, both commands first take a spaced symbol and then remove space from it. Is there a more direct definition of the form

```
\newcommand{\unspacedOpenColon}{\Umathchar"…"…"02982 }
```

?  I don't know what to put in as the math type and family arguments.

Here's some code to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,Extension=.otf,range={"2982},BoldFont=XITSMath-Bold]{XITSMath-Regular}
\newcommand{\unspacedOpenColon}{{⦂}}
\begin{document}
\(a⦂b\ c\unspacedOpenColon d\)
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Spaces are neither added nor removed. A `\mathord` is not surrounded by spaces, end of the story.

Comment: @egreg Of course `\mathord` removes spacing from a relation symbol.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong: no space is inserted to begin with.

Comment: @egreg I've just added an example. A plain ⦂ in a⦂b produces spaces around it. Strictly speaking, of course, spacing is produced by TeX when it sees an ordinary symbol (here, `a`) + a relation symbol (here, `⦂`) + an ordinary symbol (here, `b`). Orlese I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is essentially no difference with the following four definitions:

```
\newcommand{\testA}{\mathord⦂}
\newcommand{\testB}{\mathord{⦂}}
\newcommand{\testC}{{⦂}}
\Umathchardef\testD="0 "2 `⦂
```

One could also do

```
\newcommand{\testD}{\Umathchar"0 "2 `⦂ }
```

for the fourth one, but it's less efficient. Actually there are some *negligible* differences: in cases 2 and 3 TeX makes a subformula, but then realizes that it contains a single symbol so the subformula is raised to the upper level.

Granted, number 4 is the most efficient, but with the drawback that you need to guess the math group, which may not be `"2` if more math fonts are loaded.

When TeX finds something that's declared `\mathord` or braced (cases 1,2 and 3), it adds no space around it.

If you think that it first inserts spaces and then removes them, you're on the wrong track.

Spaces are inserterted (or not) at a further stage than making a math list. When TeX examines a math formula in order to do a math list, it marks every atom in it with its type (say relation or ordinary). Then the math list is passed on to the following stage when it's transformed into a horizontal list (boxes and glue): at this stage spaces are inserted in the appropriate place depending on the rules about consecutive types of atoms. Since `\mathord⦂` has produced an **Ord** atom, no space is inserted around it, unless preceded or followed by other atoms such as **Rel** or **Op**, according to the rules. The fact that `⦂` by itself is a relation symbol has no effect at this stage.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! By saying "math group", do you mean "math family" in terms of § 2.3 of the xetex-reference.pdf on p. 23?

Comment: @AlbertNash The usual LaTeX terminology is math group, plain TeX uses math family. This is to avoid misunderstandings with “font families”.

Comment: I see. Looking into The TeXBook, I see that family 2 is for symbol fonts and these range between 0 and 15, including both. However, in xetex-reference.pdf, I see that the range is given by 0-255. Which actions could change the correspondence "2 = math symbols"? In the preamble of my non-minimal example, I only say which symbols to take from which fonts via `\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX,Extension=.otf,range={…}]{…}`. Can these commands change the correspondence "2 = math symbols"?

Comment: @AlbertNash XeTeX and LuaTeX extend the number of available math groups/families to 256 (from the 16 in TeX); family 2 is reserved for a font that qualifies as the symbol font because it must have suitable `\fontdimen` parameters, which are used in order to build math lists (the boxes and glue phase). But you can declare as many math fonts as you like (well not more than 253) with `unicode-math` and each will receive a different math group number. For instance, Latin Modern Math lacks the open colon symbol and you may want to take it from a different math font; then you have to guess.

Comment: \Umathchardef\unspacedOpenColon="0"2`⦂  works like a charm for me!

Comment: @AlbertNash You like to live dangerously…